# ES6 javascript import external js file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader, es6-modules

I'm trying this in my ES6 javascript module:

```
import externalutil from 'https://externalutil.com/js/externalutil.js';
```

but it fails with this transpile error:

```
Module not found: 'https://externalutil.com/js/externalutil.js'
```

The file externalutil.js is an old-fashioned javascript library that does not export anything.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot `import` URL's (as of yet). You should download the file, put it somewhere locally and reference it locally as well.

However in your case, I'd just use a `<script />` tag to include it in your html and just access the `window` object. Converting it would be more hassle than it would be beneficial.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Will that work with a plan javascript library that does not export anything?

Comment: It would be great if it exports something otherwise it won't work, unless it writes to the `window` object?

Comment: It does indeed write to the windows-object in the last line of the file. How can this be integrated with my ES6 application? I realize that I can load the script from the index.html root page using a normal script tag and then access window.externalutil. Are there better ways?

Comment: In this case, I'd just use a `<script />` tag to include it in your html and just access the `window` object. Converting it would be more hassle than it would be beneficial.

Comment: If you add this to your answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer. I think this is a reasonable approach.